# How do I use a new-line replacement in a BSD sed?

Tags: regex, sed, bsd

Greetings, how do I perform the following in BSD sed?

```
sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

From the man-page it states that \n will be treated literally within a replacement string, how do I avoid this behavior? Is there an alternate?

I'm using Mac OS Snow Leopard, I may install fink to get GNU sed.

Comment: Small correction: `\n` isn't treated literally as such, it gets translated to literal `n` (i.e., the `\` is dropped; but that obviously still isn't the desired outcome).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In a shell, you can do:

```
    sed 's/ /\
/g'
```

hitting the enter key after the backslash to insert a newline.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Wooble. Is there any known reason why BSD sed doesn't support \n in the replacement string? Just curious.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems they just decided to not support escapes at all in the replacement string.

sed 'y/ /\n/' seems to work, although it only does string replacement; if you need to replace the ' ' with a regex it will fail.  Also, the \n seems to be special-cased; \r with get you an 'r', not a carriage return.

Answer (score 10):

Another way:

```
sed -e 's/ /\'$'\n/g'
```

See [here](http://cafenate.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac/).

Comment: +1, but note that this relies on a shell feature, [ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (`$'...'`), and some shells do not support it (e.g., `dash` - it's not part of POSIX). Also,`'s/ /\'$'\n''/g'` - wedging a `$'\n'` between two single-quoted strings - is conceptually clearer and more robust. Alternatively, use `$'s/ /\\\n/g'` (note the need to escape the `\ `).

Answer (score 7):

For ease of use, i personally often use

```
cr="\n" 
# or (depending version and OS)
cr="
"

sed "s/ /\\${cr}/g"
```

so it stays on 1 line.

Comment: Interesting; can I suggest calling the variable `nl` rather than `cr`? Assuming you use a shell that supports [ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (e.g., `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`), you could simplify the assignment to `cr=$'\n'`; then you wouldn't have to worry about platform differences.

Comment: cool advice, sur about the `$'\n'` on any "unix" ? it will indeed help (my Sun give me some issue on assignation/action like that with `\n`)

Comment: `$'\n'` (ANSI-C quoting) should work if you have the right _shell_ (`bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh` - NOT in POSIX-features-only shells such as `dash`, however), so the platform should not matter. (`bash` introduced the feature in version 2.0 (a loooong time ago) - not sure about `ksh`, and `zsh`, but I would expect current systems to have recent-enough versions).

Comment: In NetBSD 9.3, this gives me the error `unterminated substitute in regular expression` :-( I genuinely cannot find a way to make `sed` use newlines in NetBSD, but you could use `awk -v RS=" " "{print}"` instead, taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/461148)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @sikmir's answer: In Bash, which is the default shell on Mac OS X, all you need to do is place a `$` character in front of the quoted string containing the escape sequence that you want to get interpreted. Bash will automatically translate it for you.

For example, I removed all MS-DOS carriage returns from all the source files in `lib/` and `include/` by writing:

```
grep -lr $'\r' lib include | xargs sed -i -e $'s/\r//'
find . -name '*-e' -delete
```

BSD `grep` would have interpreted `'\r'` correctly on its own, but using `$'\r'` doesn't hurt.

BSD `sed` would have misinterpreted `'s/\r//'` on its own, but by using `$'s/\r//'`, I avoided that trap.

Notice that we can put `$` in front of the entire string, and it will take care of all the escape sequences in the whole string.

```
$ echo $'hello\b\\world'
hell\world
```