# unix prepend line to file without buffer/copy

Tags: file, unix, sed

I want this, the sed solution looks good, but when I tried it seems to create a huge temp file.

[unix command to prepend text to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587615/unix-command-to-prepend-text-to-a-file)

I have big sql file that is like 28 gigs, I dont have much space on file system and just want to add one line to the front of the file. How can I do this without using up more file space?

Comment: Can you put the one line in a separate file, and then use `cat single-line-file 28-gigabyte-file | program-that-reads-the-data`?  This avoids creating the file explicitly on disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, on every OS and file system I've ever seen, prepending can't generally be done in place like appending can. One might argue that file systems could do it efficiently, if the amount of data was some multiple of the underlying file system block size, but since that would not generally be the case, I don't know of any that have actually implemented such functionality. So, probably, the only way to do it is through a temporary file or copy. You could, however, use compression to somewhat alleviate the space crunch, but that would require some prework, and may not ultimately be suitable. Something along these lines:

```
1) gzip original_file.sql    # or bzip2 or whatever
2) create new_file.sql with data to be prepended
3) (cat new_file.sql; zcat original_file.sql.gz) | gzip > updated_file.sql.gz
4) zcat updated_file.sql.gz | less  # inspect the top of the file to make sure it looks right
5) rm original_file.sql.gz new_file.sql
6) gunzip updated_file.sql.gz # if necessary to have uncompressed text available - if not, just leave it compressed
```

Comment: Even though not the answer I was looking for, seems to be true and the consensus.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

// Prepend size must be less than this value
#define bufSize 1024000

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    FILE *fil;
    unsigned char *smallBuf, *mainBuf;
    size_t sReadSize, mReadSize;
    long readPos = 0, writePos = 0;
    int appendSize;

    if( argc != 3 )
    {
        printf( "Usage: %s, <prepend_line> <file>\n", argv[0] );
        return 1;
    }

    sReadSize = appendSize = strlen( argv[1] ) + 1;

    smallBuf = (unsigned char *) malloc( appendSize );
    mainBuf = (unsigned char *) malloc( bufSize );
    if( !smallBuf || !mainBuf )
    {
        printf( "No memory\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    memcpy( smallBuf, argv[1], appendSize );
    smallBuf[ appendSize - 1 ] = '\n';

    fil = fopen( argv[2], "rb+" );
    if( !fil )
    {
        printf( "Cannot open file\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    while( 1 )
    {
        fseek( fil, readPos, 0 );
        readPos += mReadSize = fread( mainBuf, 1, bufSize, fil );

        fseek( fil, writePos, 0 );
        writePos += fwrite( smallBuf, 1, sReadSize, fil );

        if( mReadSize < bufSize )
        {
            if( mReadSize > 0 )
                fwrite( mainBuf, 1, mReadSize, fil );
            break;
        }

        fseek( fil, readPos, 0 );
        readPos += sReadSize = fread( smallBuf, 1, appendSize, fil );

        fseek( fil, writePos, 0 );
        writePos += fwrite( mainBuf, 1, mReadSize, fil );

        if( sReadSize < appendSize )
        {
            if( sReadSize > 0 )
                fwrite( smallBuf, 1, sReadSize, fil );
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose( fil );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have a 2 buffers, first I read 1 block, write prepend, read second, write first,... Please, be more attentive.

Comment: Yes, I see that on a closer inspection. I'll edit the original comment, but I would still observe that this is a dangerous operation, especially as the original question is about a multi-GB file. Modifying in place is prone to catastrophic failure in case of power outages, accidental early termination of the program, or any number of other factors, which would leave the only copy of the file partially modified (although probably in at least a somewhat predictable way, ignoring caching/writeback timing issues).

Comment: Joelio asked for a simple suggestion which doesn't need additional memory. Of cause, It may be fault-resistant, by adding a temporary file with buffers content and current progress information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl for this:

```
perl -i -n -e 'print "xxx\n$_" if $.==1;print if $.!=1' your_file
```

Comment: `-i` uses a temp file behind the scenes.