# Set autocommit=0 inside ssh command

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, autocommit

I want to run a SSH command using a cron and I want to extent this cron by adding `autocommit=0` So that auto commit is disabled.

How can I achieve this?

Command:

```
mysql dbname -u dbuser -p'password' < /path/to/the/sqlscript/var/sql/stock.sql
```

Comment: Assuming you cannot modify the SQL script?  What you need to do is probably concatenate `SET autocommit = 0;` and your script and send the concatenation result to stdin, so this is more of a bash question than a MySQL question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587615/unix-command-to-prepend-text-to-a-file) to prepend / append a string to a file. A simple way:

```
(echo "set autocommit=0;"; cat stock.sql; echo "set autocommit=1") | mysql dbname -udbuser -ppassword
```