# How to prepend a file using fish

Tags: shell, command-line, fish, prepend

I saw there were several good answers for `bash` and even `zsh`(i.e. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587615/unix-command-to-prepend-text-to-a-file)). Although I wasn't able to find a good one for `fish`.

Is there a canonical or clean one to prepend a string or a couple of lines into an existing file (in place)? Similar to  what `cat "new text" >> test.txt` do for append.

Comment: What do you want to prepend *to* the file?

Comment: Could be a simple string or a couple of lines (i.e. `#!/bin/bash\n`). Will update the question

Comment: It seems to me that the canonical sh/bash/ksh implementations would be pretty trivial to adopt. Did you run into a specific problem while trying to do so?

Comment: (by the way, the caveat that prepending to a file is inefficient on all filesystems with traditional unixlike semantics -- and is therefore best avoided when you don't know that your files are short -- will apply to fish as much as anywhere else).

Comment: Also, if the intent is to modify the file in place you should say so. Otherwise the answer is trivial: `echo a line; cat a-file`.

Comment: Or `echo "new line" | cat - /path/to/original_file.txt # > /path/to/new_file.txt` (remove the `#` to write out to file immediately instead of to `stdout`).

Comment: @CJK that doesn't work as I get an `cat: test.txt: input file is output file` as return. I do not want to create another file, only prepend the same.

Comment: @KurtisRader Improved the question :) Is it clearer now?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42822247/7827713) you'll see there's a good one for `zsh`. I was looking for a similar one for fish. 
If I try `sed` it does work.

Comment: Which one, **specifically**, do you consider good? The first one, which creates a different output file? Or the other two, which require moreutils.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the one that is stated as `Here String (zsh only)`. The first one doesn't work on fish either.

Comment: That "Here String (zsh only)" one requires moreutils. I'll add an answer using it with fish, but note that you'll need to install moreutils before it'll work, same as was the case with the original zsh version.

Comment: @Paiusco, ...btw, note that `sponge` is just creating a new file and renaming it over the destination when done (which is also what `sed -i` does); obvs., you can do that yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of fish's intentional aim towards simplicity, it avoids syntactic sugar found in zsh. The equivalent to the zsh-only code `<<< "to be prepended" < text.txt | sponge text.txt` in fish is:

```
begin; echo "to be prepended"; cat test.txt; end | sponge test.txt
```

`sponge` is a tool from the `moreutils` package; the fish version requires it just as much as the zsh original did. However, you could replace it with a function easily enough; consider the below:

```
# note that this requires GNU chmod, though it works if you have it installed under a
# different name (f/e, installing "coreutils" on MacOS with nixpkgs, macports, etc),
# it tries to figure that out.
function copy_file_permissions -a srcfile destfile
  if command -v coreutils &>/dev/null  # works with Nixpkgs-installed coreutils on Mac
    coreutils --coreutils-prog=chmod --reference=$srcfile -- $destfile
  else if command -v gchmod &>/dev/null  # works w/ Homebrew coreutils on Mac
    gchmod --reference=$srcfile -- $destfile
  else
    # hope that just "chmod" is the GNU version, or --reference won't work
    chmod --reference=$srcfile -- $destfile
  end
end

function mysponge -a destname
  set tempfile (mktemp -t $destname.XXXXXX)
  if test -e $destname
    copy_file_permissions $destname $tempfile
  end
  cat >$tempfile
  mv -- $tempfile $destname
end

function prependString -a stringToPrepend outputName
  begin
    echo $stringToPrepend
    cat -- $outputName
  end | mysponge $outputName
end

prependString "First Line" out.txt
prependString "No I'm First" out.txt
```

Comment: Alternatively, instead of using `sponge` you could write to a temporary file and replace the original with it afterwards - `echo "to be prepended" | cat - file > temp; mv temp file`

Comment: Yup. If you read the comments on the question, the OP considered a `sponge`-based zsh answer the ideal they wanted to duplicate, which is why I went this route.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Maybe it's worth to also add a non-inline solution like faho commented as an alternative. (maybe a fish homemade function that would make it transparent too)

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case that file size is small to medium (fit in memory), consider using the `ed` program, which will avoid the temporary files by loading all data into memory. For example, using the following script. This approach avoid the need to install extra packages (moreutils, etc.).

```
#! /usr/env fish
function prepend
  set t $argv[1]
  set f $argv[2]
  echo '0a\n$t\n.\nwq\n' | ed $f
end
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oops, I've missed the tag. Revised the answer to show how to use `ed` from fish

Comment: You should also change the shebang to `#! /usr/bin/env fish`.