# Perl simple one-liner used to add header to a file doesn't work when input file is empty

Tags: perl

We have in code one-liner used to add header to file. It looks like

`perl -pi -e 'print "name, function, group\n" if $. == 1' CSV_FILE_NAME`

Everything is fine except when CSV_FILE_NAME is empty then no header is added to CSV_FILE_NAME.
So CSV_FILE_NAME after this command is still empty.

Comment: If the file is empty, then there is no line 1. So header isn't written to.

Comment: You might consider a few solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587615/unix-command-to-prepend-text-to-a-file

Answer (score 1):

Bartosz,

This one-liner won't work on empty files because actually it looks this way:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -i -pe 'print "name, function, group\n" if $. == 1' test.txt
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    print "name, function, group\n" if $. == 1;
}
    continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

When `readline()` tries to read from an empty file, it immediately hits `eof` (end of file) and the `while` loop ends right away. So, whatever workarounds one may try, for example placing a call to `system()` into the `else{ }` block:

```
perl -i -pe 'if ($.==1) { print "1, 2, 3\n" } else { system("echo 1, 2, 3 > test.txt") }' test.txt
```

this block won't have the chance to be executed:

```
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
if ($. == 1) {
    print "1, 2, 3\n";
}
else {
     system 'echo 1, 2, 3 > test.txt';
     }
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

One solution is "to prime" empty files with something, making them non-empty. This script enters a new line into every empty file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) # for each file on the command line: primer.pl file1 file2 file3...
{
  if (-z $file) # if the file has zero size
  {
    open my $fh, ">>", $file or die "$0: Cannot open  $file: $!";
    print   $fh "\n";
    close   $fh              or die "$0: Cannot close $file: $!";
  }
}
```

After you have run this script on your empty files, you can apply on them your one-liner and it will work as expected.