# Convert line endings to other line endings using basic unix tools on Mac OS X (sed, tr, etc.)

Tags: macos, unix, sed, newline

In particular I'm trying to transform all `\r\n` to `\r\r\n`. This is because iCloud's IMAP server sends `\r\r\n` breaking the protocol and all sensibility (my only working theory is they did this so they would only work with their own IMAP client on release some years ago), and I need to write unit tests to simulate this.

It's remarkably tricky getting this to work in standard unix tools because of how they deal with line endings.

`sed 's/\r\n/\r\r\n/g'` - nope, does nothing

`sed  's/\r/\r\r/g'` - also does nothing

`tr` doesn't do much good in dealing with strings; it only operates on single characters and seems to preserve # of characters.

I'm not actually sure how to use Unix tools to do something this low level.  Worst-case I can do this in a few lines of C but I'd like to learn how to do this more standardly.

Per discussion in Jim's answer, the version of sed on Mac OS X (BSD) seems to behave differently from Linux.  Ideally I need a Mac solution although I can more or less get this done on a different machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'sed' on MacOSX has slightly different behavior than on linux. You may want to try instructions from [this source](http://cafenate.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac/).

```
sed -e 's/ /\'$'\n/g'
```

which adds a new line.

There is another option to use 'gsed', which is a more modern version of sed (comparable to linux). There you can probably use the linux solution: sed 's/\r\n/\r\r\n/g'

Comment: You want to include information from the linked article. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183670/183887

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `bash` as your shell, you can use its [ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) feature to force Mac OS X `sed` to work as you need.

```
sed -e $'s/$/\r\r/'
```

The `$'...'` is an ANSI C quoted string.  The majority (just) of the characters within are not changed; the two `\r` sequences are replace by a carriage return in the string.

For example:

```
$ sed -e $'s/$/\r\r/' genouterr.sh | odx
0x0000: 23 21 2F 62 69 6E 2F 62 61 73 68 0D 0D 0A 66 6F   #!/bin/bash...fo
0x0010: 72 20 69 20 69 6E 20 7B 30 31 2E 2E 35 30 7D 0D   r i in {01..50}.
0x0020: 0D 0A 64 6F 0D 0D 0A 20 20 65 63 68 6F 20 22 73   ..do...  echo "s
0x0030: 74 64 6F 75 74 20 24 69 22 0D 0D 0A 20 20 65 63   tdout $i"...  ec
0x0040: 68 6F 20 22 73 74 64 65 72 72 20 24 69 22 20 3E   ho "stderr $i" >
0x0050: 26 32 0D 0D 0A 64 6F 6E 65 0D 0D 0A               &2...done...
0x005C:
$
```

The hex dump (`odx` is a home-brew program but I like its format) shows that there are two `\r` (0D) bytes before each newline (0A) which were not there in the original.  Clearly, the choice of hex dump program doesn't affect the effectiveness of the `sed` command and the ANSI C quoting mechanism.

If you needed to change CRLF to CRCRLF, then you'd use:

```
sed -e $'s/\r$/\r\r/'
```

If you wanted to remove carriage returns, but only at the end of a line, then you could use:

```
sed -e $'s/\r\r*$//'
```

(`tr` can be used to remove all carriage returns, but not only those that precede a newline.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the end-of-line anchor character '$' to accomplish what you want:

```
% od -c foo
0000000   l   i   n   e   1  \r  \n   l   i   n   e   2  \r  \n   l   i
0000020   n   e   3  \r  \n
0000025
% sed 's/\r$/\r\r/g' < foo > bar
% od -c bar
0000000   l   i   n   e   1  \r  \r  \n   l   i   n   e   2  \r  \r  \n
0000020   l   i   n   e   3  \r  \r  \n
0000030
```

The above works on GNU sed, but not BSD sed (which doesn't treat \r 
as one would expect in the replacement string).  On a Mac or other BSD-ish sed variant, you should be able to accomplish the
desired replacement by specifying a backslash-escaped *literal* (whitespace) ASCII return
character.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1421478/153430) for further details.

Comment: This didn't work - when I run that and then run the output through `od -c` I see `\r \n`, not `\r \r \n`.

Comment: Operating system must matter here since I don't get that behavior. I'm on Mac OS X.

Comment: @djechlin: It works for me, on Linux.  I added the before/after `od -c` output.

Comment: I ran this on a Linux machine and it worked.  I guess I can deal with it there.  I'll upvote this and amend the question to ask for Mac solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this **on OSX is by using awk**:

```
awk '/\r$/ {printf "%s\r\n", $0}' file
```

If you want **sed only** then this should work on OSX:

```
sed -i.bak "s/"$'\r'"$/&&/" file
```