# Replace "\n" with newline in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm tailing logs and they output `\n` instead of newlines.

I thought I'd pipe the `tail` to `awk` and do a simple replace, however I cannot seem to escape the newline in the regex. Here I'm demonstrating my problem with `cat` instead of `tail`:

`test.txt`:

```
John\nDoe
Sara\nConnor
```

```
cat test.txt | awk -F'\\n' '{ print $1 "\n" $2 }'
```

Desired output:

```
John
Doe
Sara
Connor
```

Actual output:

```
John\nDoe

Sara\nConnor
```

So it looks like `\\n` does not match the `\n` between the first and last names in test.txt but instead the newline at the end of each line.

It looks like `\\n` is not the right way of escaping in the terminal right? This way of escaping works fine in e.g. Sublime Text:

[image: regex working in ST3]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

How about this?

```
$ cat file
John\nDoe
Sara\nConnor

$ awk '{gsub(/\\n/,"\n")}1' file
John
Doe
Sara
Connor
```

Comment: Why you are using `awk`? `sed` seems more appropriate for *editing* files.

Comment: op tagged the awk tag.

Comment: You could change `"\n"` with `RS` and get `awk '{gsub(/\\n/,RS)}1'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Ok, this is a valid reason. :) I think, although in most situations you can use both `sed` or `awk`,  `sed` is for such *editing* tasks. `awk` is more for analytical tasks. Also you should never forget `grep` (not in this question)

Comment: Maybe I should not have tagged this `awk` but I did, and this answer works. However the `sed` seems better for this task? The problem is `sed` behaves weird on Mac OSX, see @DarkDust and @Ed Morton answers.

Comment: @Cotten i'm not compel you. Go for anyother solution which seems best for you.

Answer (score 15):

Using GNU's `sed`, the solution is pretty simple as @hek2mgl already answered (and that IMHO is the way it should work everywhere, but unfortunately doesn't).

But it's bit tricky when doing it on [Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748453/replace-comma-with-newline-in-sed) and [other *BSD UNIXes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421478/how-do-i-use-a-new-line-replacement-in-a-bsd-sed).

The best way looks like this:

```
sed 's/\\n/\'$'\n''/g' <<< 'ABC\n123'
```

Then of course there's still AWK, @AvinashRaj has the correct answer if you'd like to use that.

Comment: This means that BSD `sed` isn't POSIX compatible.

Comment: Err, no. It's the other way around: GNU's `sed` is extending POSIX `sed`; that's why it needs `--posix` in the first place.

Comment: sure, but the code is working with `--posix` and GNU sed

Comment: I think your syntax is a little off - it should be `sed 's/\\n/\'$'\n''/g'` to insert a literal newline (generated by `$'\n'`) in the script before sed processes it. I'm not sure what the shell is making of the standalone `$` between the 2 halves of your sed script (`'s/\\n/\'` and `'\n/g'`).

Comment: So, let's actually look at the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html): the problem is that the standard does not specify whether second part of `s` (the "replacement") shall interpret `\n` or not. Since it's not a BRE and the "\" has special meaning here I'd say it shouldn't. The BSD sed's [POSIX notes](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/usr.bin/sed/POSIX) state that historic versions didn't and discarded the "\" (see point 16). So both are POSIX compatible since the standard doesn't specify the behavior.

Comment: @EdMorton: You're probably right, but interestingly both versions work (the one I've cited and your version).

Comment: Yeah, what's happening is that the shell is evaluating `$'\n/g'` before sed tries to execute the script and that expands to a literal newline followed by `/g` so it "works" by co-incidence. It would not work with different characters after the `/` that the shell would expand - `/g` just happens to be harmless.

Comment: +1, but note that the use of an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), `$'\n'`, makes the solution shell-dependent; fortunately, though, popular shells (`bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`) DO support that, but POSIX-features-only ones such as `dash` do not.

Answer (score 10):

Why use either `awk` or `sed` for this?  Use `perl`!

```
perl -pe 's/\\n/\n/g' file
```

By using `perl` you avoid having to think about posix compliance, and it will typically give better performance, and it will be consistent across all (most) platforms.

Comment: because not every system has perl installed for example.

Answer (score 9):

This will work with any sed on any system as it is THE portable way to use newlines in sed:

```
$ sed 's/\\n/\
/' file
John
Doe
Sara
Connor
```

If it is possible for your input to contain a line like `foo\\nbar` and the `\\` is intended to be an escaped backslash then you cannot use a simple substitution approach like you've asked for.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Could you explain why `GNU sed --posix` behaves differently than BSD sed (which also claims to be POSIX compatible). Is the problem caused by `GNU sed --posix` not working properly or by BSD sed not being POSIX compatible?

Comment: Sorry, no, I'd need to read the POSIX spec for sed to figure that one out and life's too short... I will say , though, that BSD awk is broken in some ways (e.g. parsing of unparenthesized ternary expressions in print statements) so maybe their sed is too?

Comment: I would need too, thought maybe you know it already... :) thx . +1 for the solution

Comment: @hek2mgl, as per POSIX, _The meaning of a <backslash> immediately followed by any character other than `'&'`, `<backslash>`, a digit, or the delimiter character used for this command, is unspecified._, so the GNU sed behaviour is conformant, as would be a sed that outputs `\n` or one that reboots your computer. A _script_ that uses `\n` there would be non-conformant (for that very reason that the behaviour is unspecified).

Answer (score 8):

I have struggled with this problem before, but I discovered the cleanest way is to use the builtin `printf`

```
printf "$(cat file.txt)" | less
```

Here is a real world example dealing with aws iam embeded json policy in the output,  the file file.txt contains:

```
{
  "registryId": "111122223333",
  "repositoryName": "awesome-repo",
  "policyText": "{\n  \"Version\" : \"2008-10-17\",\n  \"Statement\" : [ {\n    \"Sid\" : \"AllowPushPull\",\n    \"Effect\" : \"Allow\",\n    \"Principal\" : {\n      \"AWS\" : [ \"arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root\", \"arn:aws:iam::444455556666:user/johndoe\" ]\n    },\n    \"Action\" : [ \"ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability\", \"ecr:BatchGetImage\", \"ecr:CompleteLayerUpload\", \"ecr:DescribeImages\", \"ecr:DescribeRepositories\", \"ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer\", \"ecr:InitiateLayerUpload\", \"ecr:PutImage\", \"ecr:UploadLayerPart\" ]\n  } ]\n}"
}
```

after applying the above (without the less) you get:

```
{
  "registryId": "111122223333",
  "repositoryName": "awesome-repo",
  "policyText": "{
  "Version" : "2008-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Sid" : "AllowPushPull",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : [ "arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root", "arn:aws:iam::444455556666:user/johndoe" ]
    },
    "Action" : [ "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability", "ecr:BatchGetImage", "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload", "ecr:DescribeImages", "ecr:DescribeRepositories", "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer", "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload", "ecr:PutImage", "ecr:UploadLayerPart" ]
  } ]
}"
}
```

Note that the value for "policyText" is itself a string containing json.

Comment: Brilliant, simple, and works great.

Comment: Terrible if your text happens to contain a percent symbol (`%`). Use `printf "$(sed 's/%/%%/g' file.txt)"` instead

Answer (score 4):

I would use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\\n/\n/g' file
```

Comment: That does not work for me: `sed 's/\\n/\n/g' test.txt` output: line1: `JohnnDoe` line2: `SaranConnor`

Comment: It should. Try: `sed 's/\\n/\n/g' <<< 'ABC\n123'`

Comment: `sed 's/\\n/\n/g' <<< 'ABC\n123'` gives me `ABCn123`. Is this a plattform issue? I'm on OS X using zsh

Comment: `sed --posix 's/\\n/\n/g' <<< 'ABC\n123'` works. Srry, use Linux. I'm not the OSX support I'm tired of supporting this and will never get why a Mac should be used for hacking. (its not against you personally)

Comment: @hek2mgl: Then you obviously hate the *BSD's as well, Mac's UNIX tools derive from FreeBSD. Pointless and uninformed bashing.

Comment: `sed --posix 's/\\n/\n/g' <<< 'ABC\n123'` gives `sed: illegal option --` ....... (fearing another bashing) :)

Comment: @Cotten No bashing :) the `--posix` option is special for `GNU sed` to ensure sed will work in POSIX mode. It (might|will) not be available on other versions of `sed`. If your version of `sed` does not understand this option, but claims to be POSIX compatible, then just omit it.

Comment: BSD's `sed` doesn't have a `--posix`, it is POSIX conform already. GNU's `sed` has a lot of (useful) extensions to POSIX that `--posix` is supposed to disable. I found an [answer with a solution that works on all systems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19883696/400056) (tested on Mac and Linux).

Comment: ok, thanks guys. However, still with omitting --posix `sed 's/\\n/\n/g' <<< 'ABC\n123'` gives me `ABCn123`. I have an `-E` flag saying: `-E      Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.` However `sed -E 's/\\n/\n/g' <<< 'ABC\n123'` still gives me back `ABCn123`

Comment: For a (hopefully) comprehensive discussion of the differences between FreeBSD and GNU `sed` (including POSIX compliance), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375

Comment: @DarkDust, `--posix` doesn't remove GNU extensions, it makes GNU `sed` (more) POSIX-conformant. POSIX doesn't mandate not forbid `\n` to be expanded to a newline character there, it leaves the behaviour unspecified, which is why you should not use `\n` there. POSIX clearly specifies that backslash followed by a newline should be used to insert a newline. And GNU sed does it, with or without --posix.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, OP asked about tail, and on some unix variants, eg ubuntu you need to add -W interactive to awk

```
tail -f error.log | awk -W interactive '{gsub(/\\n/,"\n")}1'
```