# How can I use sed or awk to replace "\n" in text file with new lines

Tags: awk, sed

I cannot figure out how to replace `\n` in text with new lines using sed (sed) or awk (gawk). For example, I would like to have the sed or awk command replace

> hello world\nI am from Mars\n

by

> hello world
>
> I am from Mars

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574489/replace-n-with-newline-in-awk

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140763/replace-n-by-a-newline-in-sed-portably:

```
awk '{gsub("\\\\n","\n")};1' filename
```

Comment: If you use proper regexp delimiters you won't need so many backslashes. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140763/replace-n-by-a-newline-in-sed-portably#comment227806_140816.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/\\n/\n/g' file
```

With bash parameter expansion:

```
var='hello world\nI am from Mars\n'
echo "${var//\\n/$'\n'}"
```