# How do you split a long database string into multiple lines in a UNIX shell script?

Tags: unix, sed

I have the string below stored in my database column:

```
"Your ack was rejected due to the following reason: \n -- Invalid code received. \n \n Please correct the error and resend."
```

`\n` is the new line character where I want to split the line.

Expected output:

```
"Your ack was rejected due to the following reason:
-- Invalid code received.

Please correct the error and resend it."
```

Please suggest unix/sed command

Comment: Try this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140763/replace-n-by-a-newline-in-sed-portably

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace \n with newline in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574489/replace-n-with-newline-in-awk)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $STRING| sed 's/\\n/\n/g
```

This worked!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to enable interpretation of backslash escapes with the `echo` `-e` option. Given that the string may contain special characters, important to wrap it in quotes. No need to use Unix utilities like `sed` or `awk`

```
STRING=...
echo -e "$STRING"
```